# TCP Connection Terminates

Tags: tcpclient, tcp

I tried to send packets, 200k times in a loop to a server through a single tcp connection.
It was able to send few packets before the Tcp Connection got terminated.

Is this due to the TCP buffer size, that might have been reached?

Is there a solution?

Comment: Consider checking the exception/message/code you get when you notice the failure. Also, show some code to reproduce the issue. So far you have not even named the environment/language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

No,it isn't due to the TCP buffer size. That would merely have caused your sends to block. If your connection got terminated, the error that you have failed to provide in your post tells you why.